# How to give values to all structure members

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, global

I have a c++ assignment. Which is:

Write a C++ program to implement the following description:

1. Define a global structure and name it GStruct with the following members: 
   a. X as integer 
   b. Y as integer.
2. Define a local structure inside the main and name it LStruct with the following members: 
   a. X as integer 
   b. Y[3] as GStruct
3. Inside the main declare two variables V1 and V2 of type LStruct.
4. Give values to all of their members by using input statement (cin).
5. If V1 equal V2 print "They are equal" else print "Not Equal".

I did everything that's asked from me and i got no errors. But it's not working like it's asked from me. Been working on this questions for more than 5 hours. It's driving me crazy. I went over it like 100 times and no use. Please help.... 
This is what i came up with and am sure it's all right but there is something missing but i don't know what it is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct GStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    struct LStruct
    {
        int x;
        GStruct y[3];
    };
    LStruct V1;
    LStruct V2;

    cin>>V1.x;
    cout<<V1.x<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>V1.y[i].x;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>V1.y[i].y;
    }


    cin>>V2.x;
    cout<<V2.x<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>V2.y[i].x;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>V2.y[i].y;
    }


    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (V1.y[i].x == V2.y[i].x && V1.y[i].y == V2.y[i].y && V1.x == V2.y)
            continue;
        else
            cout<<"Not equal"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would start with a proper indentation of code so that you can read it easily and actually see what you are doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: What is the expected result and the current result?

Comment: What's `V1.x == V2.y` in your equality test? It must be `V2.x`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change `V1.x == V2.y` to `V1.x == V2.x` as suggested prior to me.
Then change the equality checking to this because you only want two objects to be equal if all the members all equal.

```
bool equal = true;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    if (V1.y[i].x == V2.y[i].x && V1.y[i].y == V2.y[i].y && V1.x == V2.x)
        continue;
    else
    {
        equal = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ( equal ) 
   cout<<"Equal"<<endl;
else 
   cout<<"Not equal"<<endl;
```

Comment: you made a typo V1.x == V2.y to V1.x == V2.y